# SSIS slowly changing dimension type 2 on historical data

Tags: sql, ssis, data-warehouse, scd

I have to load the below data set onto a **dimensional table**, I need to check for **Slowly Changing Dimension type 2** on Contribution column. There's **historical data** on the below dataset, I'm required to load all records including the historical data and then mark the last record active (RowIsCurrent = Y) and mark the others not active (RowIsCurrent = N, RowEndDate = GetDate()). The ClientID is the business key. What is the best way of handling this **historical data**?

**Table structure**:-
ClientID int, 
Name varchar(20),  
Contribution money,  
EffectiveDate date,  
RowisCurrent varchar(1),  
RowEndDate datetime

**Dataset**  
ClientID, Name, Contribution, EffectiveDate 
1, John, 1000, 2012-12-31 
1, John, 1100, 2013-01-31 
1, John, 1300, 2013-03-31 
1, John, 1400, 2013-10-31

Comment: are you looking for a high-level approach or a specific query?

Comment: I'm looking for a high level approach, I have a sql query that perform the above but I don't think it's sustainable.